# Qual a diferença entre um Uint8Array e um Uint8ClampedArray?

Tags: javascript

Estava lendo sobre [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) e [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) na MDN, mais especificamente na página sobre [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Typed_array_views) e me deparei com uma tabela que compara os diferentes tipos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eles são basicamente o mesmo, só que um é *"clamped"* e até agora só vi o `Uint8ClampedArray` sendo utilizado com canvas.

Na documentação diz:

> The **Uint8ClampedArray** typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers clamped to 0-255;

Só que qualquer inteiro *unsigned* de 8 bits vai conter apenas números entre 0 e 255.

Então gostaria de perguntar, qual é a diferença entre [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) e [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray)?

Comment: No `Uint8ClampedArray`se especificarmos valores fora do intervalo 0-255 eles serão alterados para 0 ou 255. Se especificarmos um valor não inteiro ele será alterado para o inteiro mais próximo.

Comment: e no Uint8Array não é assim? Qual a diferença?

Comment: No `Uint8Array` o valor atribuído baseia-se nos primeiros 8 bits do valor especificado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

A diferença entre ambas acontece quando tentamos inserir um valor inteiro fora intervalo permitido (`0` e `255` inclusive).

> [`Uint8ClampedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray)

- Se for um número negativo, o valor será `0`
- Se for um número maior que 255, o valor será `255`

```js
let array = new Uint8ClampedArray([-1, 0, 255, 256]);
// resultado: Uint8ClampedArray([0, 0, 255, 255]);
```

> [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

Sempre guarda os 8 bits menos significantes (a direta):

```js
let array = new Uint8Array([-1, 0, 255, 256]);
// resultado: Uint8Array([255, 0, 255, 0]);
```

Pois:

```
┌─────────┬────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Decimal │       Binário (8bits finais)       │      8bits      │
├─────────┼────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│      -1 │ 111111111111111111111111(11111111) │ 11111111 == 255 │
│     256 │ 000000000000000000000001(00000000) │ 00000000 == 0   │
└─────────┴────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

---

## Resposta completa

A diferença entre [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) e [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) está na atribuição de valores aos seus respectivos itens.

Na [especificação do ECMAScrpt 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-49) mostra que a operação de conversão para `Uint8Array`e `Uint8ClampedArray` são diferentes. Sendo elas:

- **[ToUint8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint8)** (usada em Uint8Arrays):

  > 

  1. Let *number* be `ToNumber(argument)`.
  2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(number)`.
  3. If *number* is **NaN**, **+0**, **−0**, **+∞**, or **−∞**, return **+0**.
  4. Let *int* be the mathematical value that is the same sign as *number* and whose magnitude is `floor(abs(number))`.
  5. Let *int8bit* be *int* `modulo` 2<sup>8</sup>.
  6. Return *int8bit*.
- **[ToUint8Clamp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-touint8clamp)** (usada em Uint8ClampedArrays):

  > 

  1. Let *number* be `ToNumber(argument)`.
  2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(number)`.
  3. If *number* is **NaN**, return **+0**.
  4. If *number* ≤ 0, return **+0**.
  5. If *number* ≥ 255, return **255**.
  6. Let *f* be `floor(number)`.
  7. If *f* + 0.5 < number, return *f* + 1.
  8. If *number* < *f* + 0.5, return *f*.
  9. If *f* is odd, return *f* + 1.
  10. Return *f*.

---

O que as duas fazem é basicamente:

- Converter o valor para um inteiro de 8 bits
- Tratar alguns casos especiais como `NaN`, `Infinity`, etc...

A principal diferença está nessa conversão para inteiro onde:

- **[Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)**: trunca o valor para inteiro e utiliza apenas os últimos 8 bits do número, ignorando os restantes.

  Seria análogo a:

  ```
    let n = meuNumero;
    n = n & 0xff;
  ```

  Exemplo:

  ```js
  let array = new Uint8Array([
      0,    // 0x00000000
      255,  // 0x000000ff
      256,  // 0x00000100
      -1    // 0xffffffff
  ]);

  // Usa apenas os 8 bits da direita (últimos 2 caracteres hexadecimais)
  console.log(array[0]);  // 00
  console.log(array[1]);  // ff
  console.log(array[2]);  // 00
  console.log(array[3]);  // ff
  ```
- **[Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray)**: arredonda o valor usando ["round half to even"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) (se o número for `N.5` o arredondamento é feito para o número par mais próximo, ex: `2.5 → 2` e `1.5 → 2`). Se o valor arredondado for menor que `0` o valor será `0`, se o valor for maior que `255` o valor será `255`.

  Seria análogo a:

  ```
    let n = meuNumero;

    if (n < 0) {
        n = 0;
    }

    if (n > 255) {
        n = 255;
    }
  ```

  Exemplo:

  ```js
  let array = new Uint8ClampedArray([0, 255, 256,-1])

  // Se o valor for menor que zero, o valor será 0
  // Se o valor for maior que 255, o valor será 255
  console.log(array[0]);  // 0
  console.log(array[1]);  // 255
  console.log(array[2]);  // 255
  console.log(array[3]);  // 0
  ```